# SelectList is causing me to get null values

Tags: html, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, tag-helpers

In my ASP.NET Core project, I get null values to my models because of selectList. My all properties posts null from my view except my selection from dropdownlist which I selected with selectList. I'm trying to get dropdown select with asp-items which is tag helper. I want to set all data from HTML form and hold in the same model which names "Student"

My model;

```
public class Student
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string branch { get; set; }

}
```

My controller and my line which I send my selectList;

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Signup(Student student) //properties of student come null except branch.
{
    ViewBag.branches = new List<string>() { "Web Programlama", "Mobil Programlama", "Veri Bilimi", "Yapay Zeka/Makine Öğrenmesi", "Genel Tavsiye" };
    return View();      
}
```

and my HTML line which I call selectedList;

```
<select asp-for="student.branch" class="form-control" id="alan" asp-items="@(new SelectList(ViewBag.branches))"> //here is where ı stuck :(
<option disabled selected title="Alanınızı seçiniz">Alanınızı seçiniz</option>
</select>
```

Comment: How do you init your `@model` at the top of HTML?

Comment: I have TotalModel class which includes all my model classes;                                     `public class TotalModel
    {
        public User user { get; set; }
        public Mentor mentor { get; set; }
        public Student student { get; set; }
        public Branch branch { get; set; }
    }`                                                                                                                              
      and top of HTML;                                                                                        
       `@model MENTOR.Models.TotalModel`

Comment: @AlperenÖz `asp-for="student.branch"` this might not map to the student model directly. Update your action method to accept `TotalModel` and see if then you have values. In order for auto mapping, `name` of the html elements should match with the model properties. If you inspect your current `select`, its name would be `student_branch` which won't be mapped to `branch` directly. Structure needs to match.

Comment: @Pirate Yesss it worked! You saved my day :))  All I did was rename the `student.branch` with `branch`. But I still don't get the logic right I guess. :// Why is it different in the `select` tag when you can get other properties successfully with student.branch?

Comment: @Pirate and my controller method still accept Student class as a action parameter

Comment: @AlperenÖz if you changed your `select` to just have `branch`, it will work with `Student` class bcoz `branch` matches `branch`. Previously, `student.branch` not same as `branch`. I am not good at explaining this kind of things. but a simple logic here is that, `name` of html element must match the property on server if you do not do custom binding. You can also map complex objects. Read more about model binding [here](https://www.tektutorialshub.com/asp-net-core/asp-net-core-model-binding/) and [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-5.0).

Comment: @Pirate Ok it's a bit more clear now. Thanks a lot for the recommendations and for saving my day :))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly,you need to add name="branch" in `<select></select>`.And then,you need to `add value to option`.

The code

```
<select asp-for="student.branch" class="form-control" id="alan" asp-items="@(new SelectList(ViewBag.branches))"> //here is where ı stuck :(
<option disabled selected title="Alanınızı seçiniz">Alanınızı seçiniz</option>
</select>
```

in html will be like this,the options have no values:
[image]

Here is a working demo:

View:

```
<form method="post">
        
        <select asp-for="student.branch" name="branch" class="form-control" id="alan">
            //here is where ı stuck :(
            <option disabled selected title="Alanınızı seçiniz">Alanınızı seçiniz</option>
            @foreach (var branch in @ViewBag.branches)
            {
                <option value=@branch>@branch</option>
            }
        </select>
        <button type="submit">submit</button>
    </form>
```

result:
[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot !! I'll use this too :)

Comment: I just have the= `name = "branch"` and it worked in my select tag. @Yiyi You